# Hiding Specific layer from SVG document using python in inskscape

Tags: python, xml, svg, inkscape

I am trying to hide/unhide specific layers from inkscape using python. I have created a basic python file extension and managed to add text and other graphics to the svg file. But I am unable to select and manipulate existing xml elements using python. Here is what I am trying

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import inkex
from simplestyle import *
from lxml import etree, cssselect

class ClientLayoutEffect(inkex.Effect):
    """
    Example Inkscape effect extension.
    """
    def __init__(self):
        """
        Constructor.
        """
        # Call the base class constructor.
        inkex.Effect.__init__(self)

        # Define string option "--what" with "-w" shortcut and default value "World".
        self.OptionParser.add_option('-w', '--what', action = 'store',
          type = 'string', dest = 'what', default = 'World',
          help = 'What would you like to greet?')

    def effect(self):
        """
        """
        # Get script's "--what" option value.
        what = self.options.what

        # Get access to main SVG document element and get its dimensions.
        svg = self.document.getroot()
        tree = etree.parse(svg)
        for elem in tree.findall('//svg'):
            if elem.id == 'layer1':
                elem.style = 'display:none'

# Create effect instance and apply it.
effect = ClientLayoutEffect()
effect.affect()
```

When I run it I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):    
  File "client_layout.py", line 76, in <module>    
    effect.affect()    
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Inkscape\share\extensions\inkex.py", line 215, in affect    
    self.effect()    
  File "client_layout.py", line 40, in effect    
    tree = etree.parse(svg)    
  File "lxml.etree.pyx", line 2692, in lxml.etree.parse (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:49594)    
  File "parser.pxi", line 1525, in lxml.etree._parseDocument (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:71606)    
TypeError: cannot parse from 'lxml.etree._Element'
```

I am still new to python I havent traversed XML with python before but my guess is that I am calling parse() on wrong value . I am having trouble as its very difficult to find documentations for scripting extensions. I would really appreciate some help